# Vector Drawable as App Logo

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

Can we use a Vector drawable as the App logo in the Manifest file?

I am using one such drawable for my app logo, it works perfectly well.

But when I try to upload a  release version of the app on the Playstore, it shows an error stating that **Invalid Logo**.

So is it due to the reason that I am using a vector drawable as an App logo. So can't use drawables for App logo ? If we can then how ('cause vector drawables go in drawables folder and not in mipmap) ?

Comment: No you can't use Vector drawable as a launcher, you need to use PNG images an put them in the mipmap folders, for each resolution

Answer (score 0):

You can use vector drawables as launcher icon if you follow these steps:

1. Place vector launcher icon under `drawable` directory. You can't place vector drawables in `mipmap` directory because they will work only in API levels 21 and above. As you possible know it's recommended to place PNG launcher icons under `mipmap-<density>` directories instead of `drawable-<density>` ones, but that only matters if you build separate apk for each density because in this case `drawable-<density>` directories except the one for the current density will be stripped.
2. Remove `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` in `build.gradle` `defaultConfig` section if you set it earlier. This will enable build-time PNG generation for vector drawables for API levels lower then 21. If you do not remove this option than `android:icon` attribute of the `<application>` tag will load default Android "green robot" icon.

I tested it on API level 16 device and it works perfectly.